# How to manipulate a child element in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to detect a document click on the page and manipulate a dom in a div. I have something like

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('documentClick', ['$document', function($document) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function(e){
            console.log('click')
        })
    }
}]);


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl" document-click>
    <div ng-controller='insideCtrl'>
       <div id="test">
           <p>inside p</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to change 'inside p' text to something else after I click page anywhere. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Seems like you should easily be able to narrow down to that `p` by selecting the `test` id, and then getting its only descendant element. Then it's just a matter of updating its text content. Not sure what exactly you're asking about.

Comment: I want to do it in angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use events to do the trick.

Events are emitted by controllers, the only controller you can inject in your directive is `$rootController`. So let's do it :

```
// in your directive
angular.module('...')
  .directive('documentClick', function ($document, $rootScope) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function(e){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('documentClicked');
      })
    }
  });

// in your controller
angular.module('...')
  .controller('WhateverCtrl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.$on('documentClicked', function () {
       // here it is !
     });

  });
```

Note that I used `$scope` in the controller, not `$rootScope` cause there is no need to use it ad `$broadcast` is sent to all childs scopes. [See here for more infos](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).